# Killing a smart contract and recovering funds inside

Tags: contract-invocation

I’m trying to kill a contract that I set up and own.

I understand (and hope) that killing a contract will send any ETH inside the contract to the owning account.

The method I use are either MEW or MyCrypto — both seem to work similarly.

I’ll describe things using MyCrypto.

I select "contract": and fill in the details:  Contract Address, ABI/Json interface (copied from etherscan.io)

Access the contract is via the dropdown “kill” and filling in the “_to” address.  I also set VALUE to zero.
(Not sure if this is required).

To my surprise the raw transaction is

```
{
  "value": "0x0",

  "data": "0xcbf0b0c0000000000000000000000000(_to Address)“.

  "to": "0x(Contract Address)”,

...(etc)

}
```

That is, the "Contract address" and “_to” address are interchanged.    Going to the next step shows the  proposal to transfer ETH from the "_to"  account to the  "Contract address"  rather than vice versa.

Out of caution I then stop.

The same happens with MEW.

I thought it may have had something to do my particular contract.

However etherscan.io reports that there are many identical contracts to mine.    Performing the same steps on one of the similar contract leads to same flipping of the two addresses.

What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding??

Comment: Do you have the source code of the contract? Nobody can arbitrarily destroy a contract in Ethereum. The contract has have code to destroy itself. The transaction you showed appears to be correct. It is sending a send a message to the contract to destroy itself, but without the code it is just a guess.

Comment: The problem originated as described  here
https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/1071
Further email instruction from the Mist team
“Go through your old accounts on etherscan.io and find the one creating your wallet, this will have your old address. Then go to https://wallet.ethereum.org/account/new and add import wallet. Then you'll be able to move your money out to a newer account elsewhere.”
Went to the  link but there is no “import wallet” and clicking “add account” does nothing.     So I appear to be stuck.

Comment: wallet.ethereum.org seems to be out of service. If the wallet uses this [code](https://github.com/ethereum/meteor-dapp-wallet/blob/74414d36c2453a468116d5884e28eaa6eb1723e5/Wallet.sol). Only the owners can kill the contract, the contract will transfer only ethers to the target address and destroy itself (any ERC20 or any other token will be locked forever).

Comment: Yes, I’m aware of this. It needs a get node.   Downloaded and setup geth node.   But add account/wallet does nothing.   So out of frustration I want to kill contract.  I tried to find out where the contract kills to ie sends fund to.  I own the account that owns the contract so presumably I’m permissioned to kill it.  Presumably the kill will send funds to the owning account.  But how can I be sure?   The raw transaction seems to suggest otherwise—as described above.   Many thanks for your comments/help!

Comment: When you want to interact with a contract `to` is the contract address, and `data` is the encoded function call with parameters. For example [tx 0x47f7cf..](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x47f7cff7a5e671884629c93b368cb18f58a993f4b19c2a53a8662e3f1482f690) is the famous parity's multisig kill transaction `to` is the contract to be killed, and the recipient is in `data`. In the internal tab you will the suicide opcode and the recipient address.

Comment: Could not understand your last sentence “  In the internal tab you will the suicide opcode and the recipient address.”.   Maybe a typo?

Comment: At transaction page there is a tab "Internal Txns" at the top. It will show you interactions with other contracts. In this case it shows the suicide opcode that kill the contracts and transfer all remaining ethers to the recipient address.